# How do I listen for for a Android back button with Capacitor Browser Plugin

Tags: ionic-framework, capacitor

I have an ionic App that has an external webpage it links to.  I can listen for browser closing, but I also wish to listen for the user using the Android back button to return return to the App.  here is the code I use.

```
import { Browser } from '@capacitor/browser';

viewWebPage = async ( url: string ) => {
  url = this.LINK
  await Browser.open( { url: url } );
  Browser.addListener('browserFinished', () => {
    console.log("browser finished");
  });
  // add listener for back button
};
```

Comment: https://ionicframework.com/docs/developing/hardware-back-button

Comment: https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/app#addlistenerbackbutton-

Comment: None of these example work on the new window that the Browser plugin opens

Answer (score 0):

Turns out if you use the Android back button to completely exit the open browser window the Capacitor Browser plugin will capture the event with

```
import { Browser } from '@capacitor/browser';

viewWebPage = async ( url: string ) => {
  url = this.LINK
  await Browser.open( { url: url } );
  Browser.addListener('browserFinished', () => {
    console.log("browser exited");
  });
};
```